# How to set up artifcatory in Jenkins Free Style Project?

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am using Free Style Projects (in Jenkins) to schedule a regression test.

```
1. Get Source From BitBucket
2. Execute Windows Batch Command.
```

Earlier we are allowed to upload the jar files in Bitbucket. So we did not face any issue. Now Presently due to some changes in the process, we are not allowed to upload binaries which is affecting to upload jars in the Bitbucket.

Now, They gave given the artifactory url to set up for Maven. But we don't have any Maven projects.

It seems that artifactory is getting populated when it is hosted in the local. But we wanted to use the artifactory which is shared..

Can any one let me know the set up for free style project and the artifactory hosted in other machine and we have only URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is documentation:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in

I recommend to use Maven Project.